# "You look done" - does it make any sense?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, difference

1. You are done.
2. You look done.

Are these two sentences grammatically correct and make any sense? If two are correct, what are the difference between them?

*** I have learnt about "Predicate Adjectives" recently and it is found that we can use predicate adjective after linking verb. So does sentence 2 make any sense?

Comment: Looks like the dictionary has a relevant entry: [look verb (SEEM)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look) (Cambridge Dictionary). Could you [edit] your post to explain whether or not that's helpful? Do you understand the usage of "are", or "done"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 sentences are right. You decide wich to use regarding what you want to say.

1. You **are** done: it means that by the time you speak, "you" have finished performing an action or we also use this sentence to say that you won't be able to finish a certain thing (ex. "Stop running man, you are done!").
2. You **look** done: it means that it seems that you have done something (ex. Have you finished dressing? You look done!)